# Sequentially Generating a Dynamic User Interface in Shiny, R

Tags: r, shiny, selectize.js

I've created a dynamic user interface in R which generates four `selectizeInput` boxes within a fluid row environment with a matching set of observers watching for input. If an `addFilter` button is selected, then an additional fluid row is generated with another four boxes.

My issue surrounds the saving of previously inputted values. I have a group of reactive values storing the user inputs. These values are then inputted into the observers on the `updateselectize`. If a user clicks slowly, it all works fine. However, if a user clicks quickly, sometimes the values are erased.

I believe this happens because by the time the script comes to setting up the new interface, the old one with observers hasn't quite been rendered; but the values have been reset.

Below is a MWE. Note that to trigger the bug, you need to double click on the Add Filter button quickly.

Server.R:

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(session, input, output) {

  rValues <- reactiveValues(filter_counter = 1, filter_counter2 = 1, filter_waiter = 1, savedFil_1 = "", savedOp_1 = "",
                            savedCrit_1 = "", savedAO_1 = "")

  columns <- c("C1", "C2")

  operators <- c("O1", "O2")
  values <- c("V1", "V2")
  andor <- c("&&", "||")

  observeEvent(input$AddFilter,{
    if (rValues[['filter_waiter']] == 1) {
      # Step 1: Store 
      lapply(1:rValues$filter_counter, function(i) {
        rValues[[paste0("savedFil_", i)]] <- input[[paste0("fil_", i)]]
        rValues[[paste0("savedOp_", i)]] <- input[[paste0("filOperators_", i)]]
        rValues[[paste0("savedCrit_", i)]] <- input[[paste0("filCriteria_", i)]]
        rValues[[paste0("savedAO_", i)]] <- input[[paste0("andor_", i)]]
      })

      # Step 2: Increment counter
      rValues$filter_counter <- rValues$filter_counter + 1

      # Step 3: Set filter waiter
      rValues[['filter_waiter']] <- 0
    } 
  })

  output$filters <- renderUI({
    if (rValues[['filter_waiter']] == 1) {
      ui <- lapply(1:rValues$filter_counter, function(i) {
        fluidRow(
          column(4, selectizeInput(paste0("fil_", i), label = NULL, choices = NULL)),
          column(2, selectizeInput(paste0("filOperators_", i), label = NULL, choices = NULL)),
          column(4, selectizeInput(paste0("filCriteria_", i), label = NULL, choices = NULL)),
          column(2, selectizeInput(paste0("andor_", i), label = NULL, choices = NULL)))
      })
      return(ui)
    }
  })

  ### Create observers for filters
  observe({
    lapply(1:rValues$filter_counter, function(i){
      # Update the Selectizes
      updateSelectizeInput(session, paste0("fil_", i), selected = rValues[[paste0("savedFil_", i)]], choices = columns, server = TRUE)
      updateSelectizeInput(session, paste0("filOperators_", i), selected = rValues[[paste0("savedOp_", i)]], choices = operators, server = TRUE)
      updateSelectizeInput(session, paste0("filCriteria_", i), selected = rValues[[paste0("savedCrit_", i)]], choices = values, server = TRUE)
      updateSelectizeInput(session, paste0("andor_", i), selected = rValues[[paste0("savedAO_", i)]], choices =  c("", "&&", "||"), server = TRUE)
    })

    rValues[['filter_waiter']] <- 1
  })
})
```

And the UI.R:

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Dynamic SelectizeInput UI"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton("AddFilter", label = "Add a Filter"),
      uiOutput("filters")
    ),

    mainPanel(
      h1("")
    )
  )
))
```

Comment: Code formatting is personal preference.  First edit did not improve anything either.  Rolled back to original.

Comment: @DirtySockSniffer Improving clarity and readability are well established reasons for editing. Rolling back to prior revision.

Comment: @Hack-R - How does *I will not format my code like a drunk howler monkey* add anything useful to this post?  Furthermore, just because you write your assignments in line doesn't mean that's the standard.

Comment: @DirtySockSniffer That was a funny Dilbert reference way of reminding OP to format code in a readable way. By the way this Meta post validates my edit. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code Further I didn't understand your last sentence but the formatting I am using is the one developed by Google in conjunction with the R Project published by Google in a style guide...

Comment: Thank you for referencing the R Project Style as that is indeed helpful. I will make changes to my 'hack' R style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can be simplified. Yo do not need to update the selectizeInput controls as you are generating new controls each time the button is selected.
You have too many reactive variables. I change to global variables. If you do not want to use global variables, then use reactive variables with isolate.

```
library(shiny)

filter_counter <- 0
filter_values  <- list()
columns        <- c("C1", "C2") 
operators      <- c("O1", "O2")
values         <- c("V1", "V2")
andor          <- c("&&", "||") 

server<- shinyServer(function(session, input, output) {   

  output$filters <- renderUI({  

      input$AddFilter  
      # Step 1: store filter values
      if ( filter_counter>0) {
          lapply(1:filter_counter, function(i) {
            filter_values[[paste0("savedFil_", i)]]  <<- input[[paste0("fil_", i)]]
            filter_values[[paste0("savedOp_", i)]]   <<- input[[paste0("filOperators_", i)]]
            filter_values[[paste0("savedCrit_", i)]] <<- input[[paste0("filCriteria_", i)]]
            filter_values[[paste0("savedAO_", i)]]   <<- input[[paste0("andor_", i)]]
          })
      }

      # Step 2: Increment counter 
      filter_counter <<-  filter_counter + 1 

      # Step 3: generate selectInputs
      ui <- lapply(1:filter_counter, function(i){ 
          fluidRow(
              column(4,selectizeInput(paste0("fil_", i), label= 'fil', selected = filter_values[[paste0("savedFil_", i)]], choices = columns )),
              column(2,selectizeInput(paste0("filOperators_", i),label= 'filop',  selected = filter_values[[paste0("savedOp_", i)]], choices = operators )),
              column(4,selectizeInput(paste0("filCriteria_", i),label= 'filcri',  selected = filter_values[[paste0("savedCrit_", i)]], choices = values )),
              column(2,selectizeInput(paste0("andor_", i),label= 'andor',  selected = filter_values[[paste0("savedAO_", i)]], choices =  c("", "&&", "||") ))
          )
      }) 

    })
})


ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Dynamic SelectizeInput UI"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton("AddFilter", label = "Add a Filter"),
      uiOutput("filters")
    ),

    mainPanel(
      h1("")
    )
  )
))

shinyApp(ui , server)
```